# How to save result of function measured by %timeit in jupyter?

Tags: python, time, jupyter-notebook

How can I both measure time of function execution and extract result of its work?
For example

```
foo = %timeit -o y = myfunc(x)
print(y)
```

will give me error, cause `y` is not known. How can I save the output of function?

Comment: @MrGeek, as far as I understand no, these questions are about capturing the result of `timeit`, I want to capture a result of `myfunc`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use `y` as a `list`, and `append` to it in the `timeit`:

```
def myfunc(x):
    return x ** 2

y = []
foo = %timeit -o y.append(myfunc(20))
print(y[: 100]) # first 100, there's millions here
```

Output:

```
[400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400]
```

Note that this is also timing `y.append`, but then [`list.append` is `O(1)`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), so it's probably not something to worry about.